# Getting the compiler to perceive << as defined for a specific class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I edited a post of mine with this question, yet got no answers.

I overloaded << for a class, `Score` (defined in score.h), in score.cpp.

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream & os, const Score & right)
{
 os << right.getPoints() << " " << right.scoreGetName();
 return os;
}
```

(`getPoints` fetches an `int` attribute, `getName` a `string` one)

I get this compiling error for a test in main(), contained in main.cpp

```
binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Score' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

How come the compiler doesn't 'recognize' that overload as valid? (includes are proper)

Thanks for your time.

EDIT:

As requested, code causing the error:

```
cout << ":::::\n" << jogador.getScore() << endl;
```

`jogador` is a `Player` object, which contains a `Score` one. `getScore` returns that attribute.

Comment: you should definitely post the code which is causing the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you didn't declare your `operator<<` in `score.h`? It should normally contain something like:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream & os, const Score & right);
```

Edit: More accurately, that should be:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Score &right);
```

You definitely should *not* have a `using namespace std;` in a header, so you need the `std::` for it to work correctly.

Comment: That won't work, because the left side parameter is not of type `Score`. At least, another question on here made me think that.

Comment: @Francisco P. - The compiler is complaining about an rvalue, not an lvalue.  Ie, it's worried about the right hand parameter.

Comment: Don't put this one line in the class declaration, put it *after* the class declaration.

Comment: Herb Sutter:  "operator<< can't be a member because it requires a stream as the left-hand argument"  http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm

Comment: @francisco: That's what it *has* to be a global function like this. As a global function, the left operand is used as the first parameter (ostream &) and the right operand as the second parameter (Score const &).

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring `operator<<` as a **friend** function in your class:

```
struct Score
{
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const Score& right);
};
```

This will allow your `Score` structure to fit nicely into printing statements:

```
Score my_score;
cout << my_score << endl;
```

When in doubt, check the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/).

Comment: I was looking for a different way to do that. Even though it works, there is no reason I need to friend operator<<. I like the accepted answer's suggestion more. But thanks for your time/effort in helping me.

Comment: This answer is helpful if Score::getPoints() and/or Score::scoreGetName() are private.  But I don't think you need the struct Score around it, by the Interface Principle.